# BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer camel bean

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I use the following bean to manage properties in camel as below :

```
 <bean id="ilePropertiesConfigurer"
    class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="allProperties" />
 </bean>
```

allproperties is a java class. it works very well when starting the application.

But now, I want to update properties without restarting my application. I update allproperties but it still takes the old values.

Can you help me?

Comment: If you got Spring applications: with Spring Cloud Config Server and Spring Cloud Bus you can broadcast configuration updates to applications without restarting them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Apache Camel with that Spring property placeholder bridge. You need to restart your application.

OSGi Blueprint has a concept of allowing to reload/restart your application when properties are changed, but it does a full bundle restart command.

Comment: Thx, would you have an example of using blueprint in my case?

Comment: Only use Blueprint if you use OSGi and run on Apache Karaf/ServiceMix etc. Your question was about Spring and therefore not possible to use blueprint.